# Не получается написать нужный sql запрос

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в базе есть две таблицы: categoties и products. Пытаюсь написать запрос, чтобы получить название категории, в которой находится максимальное количество товаров и вывести количество этих товаров.
Категории с количеством товаров получаю, а как дальше не понятно.

```
'SELECT categories.name, COUNT(products.id) FROM products, categories WHERE products.category_id = categories.id GROUP BY categories.name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отсортировать полученную выборку по убыванию по колонке, содержащей количество продуктов в категории и ограничить выборку 1 строкой с помощью оператора LIMIT. 
Таким образом в выборку попадет одна категория, содержащая наибольшее количество товаров. 
Так же, лучше использовать JOIN:

```
SELECT categories.name as category_name, COUNT(products.id) as products_cnt FROM categories 
INNER JOIN products ON products.category_id = categories.id GROUP BY categories.name 
ORDER BY products_cnt DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: спасибо! это то, что я хотела